# UITableView can't prevent array index out of bounds - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

As you can see I am using search functionality to filter the main array for the table view

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if(searchActive){ return filteredRooms.count}
    return roomlist.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive){ return filteredRooms[section].count }
    return roomlist[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let sec = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RoomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var room:RoomItem;

    if(searchActive){

        room = filteredRooms[sec][row]  // Array out of bounds here

    }else{

        room = roomlist[sec][row]

    }
```

So, shouldn't the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` run first, then `numberOfRowsInSection`, then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ??

Id this is the case then no error should be thrown, I can't possibly get an Array out of bounds error.

If the functions are not run in that order, how do I prevent the error?

**EDIT: Added Search activation code**

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredRooms = filterz(roomlist, txt: searchText)

    if(filteredRooms.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
        println("Activating search")
    }


    self.tViewRooms.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you call `reloadData` after you set `searchActive`

Comment: @sylvanaar `reloadData` is called after any text change in Search bar

Comment: You must have an error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Add the code where you set and reset your Bool searchActive

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh  Added the code

Comment: As sylvanaar said above, you have to call reloadData *each time* you change the value of searchActive.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks guys !

Comment: Are there other causes to table view reloads? I'm getting reloads that aren't triggered by me, do I need to add validation protection to prevent a crash even though I call reload afterwords?